# How can I play FLAC audio files on Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows, audio

I have Windows 7 and Windows Media Player 12 (I think it's the x86 not the x86-64 version but I'm not sure -- how can I be sure?) and I want a way to play FLAC files in it.  I want a way to do it which is seamless and reversible.  What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be sure of x64/64-bit or x86/32-bit, press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> and take a look at the `System type:` section.

As for FLAC audio on Windows Media Player, you will need a codec to play them.

By far the easiest thing to do is go to [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) and choose the `K-Lite Codecs` option. This will install K-Lite in the bare minimum configuration and should add FLAC support to Windows Media Player.

If you do not want to use Ninite, [here is a link to K-Lite's homepage.](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)

Also, if you haven't used it yet, I would highly recommend you take a look at [VLC Media Player](http://videolan.org) (Also available on Ninite). It allows FLAC audio out the box and you don't have to mess around with any messy codecs!

Answer (score 5):

[Playing FLAC files in WMP & Media Center](http://www.hack7mc.com/2009/01/playing-flac-files-in-media-center.html):

> Currently Windows Media Player and
>   Media Center don’t include native file
>   support for a number of lossless audio
>   codecs including FLAC, OGG, and
>   basically anything other than
>   Microsoft’s own WMA files. There is a
>   cure for this minor omission though so
>   no worries.
>
> We suggest that 32-bit users [download
>   and install the madFlac decoder from
>   madshi](http://www.hack7mc.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=34). For 64-bit users, codecs
>   for both [x64](http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/oggdsf/oggcodecs_0.81.15562-x64.exe) and [x86](http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/oggdsf/oggcodecs_0.81.15562-win32.exe)
>   versions of windows can be found at
>   Xiph’s open source site. The files
>   linked above are the latest versions
>   available at the time of this post but
>   you should check [Xiph’s](http://xiph.org/dshow/) page to
>   check for updated versions.

(read entire post for more details)

Answer (score 3):

The xiph.org filters work for FLAC as well as other common open source formats:

> Then Windows Media Player or any other DirectShow application (e.g. BSPlayer) will be able to play Ogg Vorbis, Ogg Speex, Ogg Theora, Ogg FLAC, native FLAC, and WebM files.

http://xiph.org/dshow/downloads/

After installing this, I was able to double-click on a .flac file and have it play back in Windows Media Player in Windows 7 x64 no problem.

(and if you need these ogg/flac music files to be indexed in the WMP music library alongside typical .mp3 and .wma and .aac music files, check out http://www.hack7mc.com/2009/01/playing-flac-files-in-media-center.html as linked by Krazy Kaos in another answer here.)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use Shark007 codec pack, as it's easy to setup and doesn't create loads of crap I don't, and bundles all the settings into 1 easy application:

[shark007.net](http://shark007.net/)

[image]